# Is multiplying two column vectors matrix multiplication?

Tags: vectors

I am self-studying vectors. I have come across a different notation style. Usually, coordinates are written (x,y,z) but this alternative style is written as a column.

Furthermore, this vector column (A) is multiplied by another vector column (B) to obtain the cross product. But this multiplication doesn't make sense to me as it violates the rule that the number of columns of A should equal the number of rows of B in order to multiply 2 matrices.

Thank you.

Comment: The cross product is not the same as matrix multiplication

Comment: I always see that $[x,y,z].[a,b,c]^{T}$ is the correct way, you interpretate as a matrix $1\times 3$ and the other matrix is $3\times 1$ and obtain a scalar number $1\times 1$

Comment: To reiterate: there are several different ways in which you can "multiply" (in some loose sense) matrices and/or vectors. The standard matrix multiplication is one way, and it's one that has constraints on rows and columns of the factors. The cross product is another way, but only works with vectors of $3$ components each (or $7$ components each). There is another called the dot product, which only works on vectors of the same size. And so on and so forth.

Comment: for $X = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{bmatrix}$ and $Y = \begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \\ y_3 \end{bmatrix}$ we have $$X \times Y = \begin{bmatrix} \begin{vmatrix} x_2 & x_3 \\ y_2 & y_3 \end{vmatrix} \\ \begin{vmatrix} x_1 & x_3 \\ y_1 & y_3 \end{vmatrix} \\ \begin{vmatrix} x_1 & x_2 \\ y_1 & y_2 \end{vmatrix} \end{bmatrix}$$
This is not the same as $XY$ @PrincessEev The cross product can be defined in general but the operation would require $n$ vectors for $n$ dimensions.

Comment: I'm perfectly aware that it is not the same as matrix multiplication, hence why I said it is only multiplication in a loose sense (all them are only really multiplication in a limited sense). If instead your objection is to the cross product in $\mathbb{R}^7$, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-dimensional_cross_product) is a Wikipedia article on it.

Comment: Thanks everyone. What I have understood from this is that the cross product is like matrix multiplication in terms of carrying out the calculation (which is enough for me). But for some other reason, it isn't actual matrix multiplication.